# Jquery datepicker year range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jquery date picker plugin in my asp.net website. 
I set the default Date to 1900-01-01 and year range to year Range to 1900:2020. The problem is when I select a date from picker and it will appear the date in text box. This is fine. But, when I select the year again, the starting year already remove those year less than what I had selected just now.
Example: If I select 2000-01-01 and select the year again, it will show year greater than 2000 only. Why like this, I think is asp.net issue because I have tried in Jsfiddle run the javascript and is working.

```js
        $(function() {
             var today = new Date();
             var year = today.getFullYear();
             
            $( "#<%=txtDOB.ClientID %>" ).attr('readonly', 'true');
            $( "#<%=txtDOB.ClientID %>" ).datepicker({
              defaultDate: "1900-01-01",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '1900:' + "'" + year + "'" ,
                maxDate: today,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#<%=txtDOB.ClientID %>" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                }
            });   
            });
```

Comment: It's a correct behaviour because in the close event you are updating "minDate" so the possible years in the dropdown are limited by this option.   Same in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dao6xqv7/ It's a strange UI usage, what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this thing over here is creating problem.

```
$( "#<%=txtDOB.ClientID %>" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
```

Try changing it to

```
$( "#<%=txtDOB.ClientID %>" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", selectedDate );
```